# Writing custom method using Devise's current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Rails 4.0.2 and Devise 3.2.2 to handle user registration / authentication.

I would like to write a custom method for Devise's `current_user` , this method is for checking how many times does the `current_user` sign in. I will be using `sign_in_count`

Do I write the method in the User model or should I define the method in Users Controller ?

Is it possilbe to write something like the below

```
def count
  user = current_user
  user.sign_in_count
end
```

and call `current_user.count` ?

Thanks

----edited----

What if I need to add other methods, am I able to add something like the below

```
#app/controllers/post_controller.rb

before_action :check_time

def check_time
    time = User.last_sign_in_at(current_user) 
    if # something
        # do bla bla
    end
end
```

Comment: why dont you use `current_user.sign_in_count` ?

Comment: @apneadiving   Oh true, how about other methods? Please see the edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Do I write the method in the User model or should I define the method in Users Controller ?
```

It depends where (& when) you want to use the method

If you're going to use it as part of the "controller-level" interactivity, you'll want to put it into the `UsersController`, but if it's going to be used on "model-level" (by multiple controllers / models), you may wish to put it into the model

Something you need to be aware of is that `current_user` is a helper, and is not available at model level:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def lookup
    sign_ins = User.sign_in_count(current_user)
    if sign_ins > 10 
        #do something
    end
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.sign_in_count(user)
        user = find(user.id)
        user.sign_in_count
    end
end
```

But as stated by `@apneadiving`, a far more efficient way to do this is to reference the `current_user.sign_in_count` attribute directly

---

**Update**

In reference to your update, you'll be best reading up about [class & instance methods](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

You could perform the method like this:

```
#app/controllers/post_controller.rb

before_action :check_time

private 
def check_time
    time = current_user.last_sign_in_at
    if # something
        # do bla bla
    end
end
```

In my references to model / controller methods - you'd use model methods if you wanted to give standard functionality on an app-wide level (such as `User.weight_gain?`). If you're using controller-centric data, you're best to keep it all in the controller

Comment: Thanks for the comment, how about other methods? Please see the edited post.